# Inserting new line characters in a string which has html code in it

Tags: java, html, string

My problem is that i have developed a tool that merges two HTML snippets ( each snippet has its own `</html><!DOCTYPE html>` tags ). I merge them into a string and then save as output.html file which can be opened in browser.

The issue is that output HTML is not formatted and all text/code wraps in single line.
How can i add new line characters after few tags in string so that the output HTML code is readable.

**Current output looks something like that:-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US"><head>  <meta charset="UTF-8" />    <title>1 abcd</title></head><body>      <header role="xyz"> </body></html><!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US"><head>    <meta charset="UTF-8" />    <title>1 efgh</title></head><body>      <header role="mnp"> </body></html>
```

**i want to make it more like this**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US"><head>  <meta charset="UTF-8" />    <title>1 abcd</title></head>
<body>      <header role="xyz"> </body>
</html>
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US"><head>  <meta charset="UTF-8" />    <title>1 efgh</title></head>
<body>      <header role="mnp"> </body>
</html>
```

Any pointers how to do it please help. I dont want to remove any tags but want to move code to new lines.

Thanks
Vishal

Comment: Use the HTML pretty-printing library/utility of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

JTidy may be helpful to you. It is a java version of HTML Tidy.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtidy/

Once you have two tidy documents it should be straight forward to trim out the excess tags and then merge them.

Comment: While this is excellent advice, and far superior to what the OP is doing, it doesn't actually answer the question, as to how can the serialized HTML have line breaks safely added to it. See http://jsfiddle.net/egn4X/2/ for why a naive approach can go wrong and how inserting the line breaks at white space inside tags (or immediately before the `>` character) can resolve it. Is there a way in JTidy to cause its serialization to do this?

Comment: It does add it's own tags. I'm not sure of the specifics but it does add/rearrange tags to correct bad/malformed html.